# undefined или ? typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Вопрос больше по красоте кода. Как лучше написать

```
SOME_PROPERTY?: string;
```

или

```
SOME_PROPERTY: string | undefined | null;
```

Comment: ну если вопрос в красоте, то как вам нравится, так и пишите.

Comment: а с точки зрения практичности?

Comment: @ПавелЮхневич практичнее (будучи ощутимо короче) первый вариант

Answer (score 0):

**Вопросительный знак** обозначает **возможность** `undefined`, а **не** `null`. Правильной является такая конструкция:

```
interface Test {
    text?: string | null;
}

const test1: Test = {
    text: null,
};

const test2: Test = {
    text: undefined,
};

const test3: Test = {
    text: "text",
};
```